# set postion of no of the UITextviews in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uitextview

I have a **UITextView** added on my UIView programmatically. The **textview** added is not editable, it is just to display some data. The data displayed in the textview is getting from array.The no of the textviews are same as texts which **I** Stored in **Array**.Textview is displaying from start to end one by one.I need to set the postion of textview one by one means first textview come and set at some postion,second will be set as just before first **textview**,third will be just before on second and so on..    **Note**: Something like using **Animation**. suppose one **textview** come from top and it stops at Y postion at 250 then next **textview** will set at just before that..it cant come upto 250 of Y postion. and so on. I have no clue how to do this. Please give me some ideas.

Comment: How many textViews do u have?

Comment: u want the oder of textviews in descending order. rite ?

Comment: @Gill:- Actually i get textviews same as text in array one by one bt the issue is the postion.All the textviews are set at same position.can u help me?

Comment: @VenkatManohar:- order dosent metter..I need that just postion of textview correctly

Comment: You have to make height dynamic, i think you are using same frame for each text view.

Comment: @kamleshwar:- yahh..I m using same frame for each textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**//loop over the substrings of type Array to add textfields at run time**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [substrings count]; i++)
{
    CGRect frame = CGrectMake(0, i * 40, 100, 30);
    UITextField * txtDynamic = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    txtDynamic.text = [substrings objectAtIndex:i];

    //add as subview
    [view addSubview:txtDynamic];

    //if you are not using ARC release the txtDynamic
}
```

**Note**
If number of UITextField more i.e it goes out of screen, then Add UITextField to UIScrollView and you can make its Size and content size dynamic.

**Hope this will give you some clue.**

Comment: I have given example of UITextField, similar way you can add UITextView.

Answer (score 3):

Don't Consider the array and the `UITextView` data.... its fot temporary..

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Ten", nil];


for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++) {
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20*i+height, 200, height)];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [textView setText:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}
```

Comment: you have to declare height and assign some value to it ;)

Comment: @VenkatManohar:- fine..done..But now I would like to add textview like animation.means it comes from view's top side to bottom one by one.can i do it?

Comment: @VenkatManohar:- suppose one textview come from top and it stops at Y postion like 250 then next textview will set at just before that..it cant come upto 250 of Y postion. and so on..I hope u get my point.

Comment: @MeiPhoneDeveloper: i Didn't try any time. But,i hope it works with [UIView animateWithDuration:] something like that.

Answer (score 2):

you want to add textviews programmatically in your view based on the array,if you are adding textviews to your view then there is a problem(if u are having more number of textviews then you must take scroll view )  that's why better to take scroll view and add scroll view to your view  after that you will add textviews to your scroll view ,

```
now take constant x-coordinate value ,width and height only change y-coordinate value and you must give the content size to scrollview .


for(int i=1;i<[array length];i++){
    text_desc = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(63,64*i,370,60)];
    text_desc.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
    text_desc.editable=NO;
    text_desc.tag=1;
}
```

and then set srollview content size,

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,total*87);
```

Answer (score 1):

hey mate then take one scrollview and in it just set all textview with its `ContentSize` like bellow

here i give an example ,

**Note:** this is just example here take one `UIScrollView` and give name scrview and after add your all this `UITextField` in it.

you add this code after you add data in textfield

```
 txt1.frame = CGRectMake(txt1.frame.origin.x,    txt1.frame.origin.y, txt1.frame.size.width, txt1.contentSize.height); 

float txtscreen1 = txt1.frame.origin.y + txt1.contentSize.height + 10;

txt2.frame = CGRectMake(txt2.frame.origin.x, txtscreen1, txt2.frame.size.width, txt2.contentSize.height);


float txtscreen2 = txt2.frame.origin.y + txt2.contentSize.height + 10;

txt3.frame = CGRectMake(txt3.frame.origin.x, txtscreen2, txt3.frame.size.width, txt3.contentSize.height);

//.....and so on to 10

float txtscreen10 = txt3.frame.origin.y + txt3.contentSize.height + 10;


txt10.frame = CGRectMake(txt10.frame.origin.x, txtscreen10, txt10.frame.size.width, txt10.contentSize.height);

float scrollviewscreen = txtscreen10.frame.origin.y + txtscreen10.frame.size.height + 20;
scrview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, scrollviewscreen);//take scrollview
```

i hope this help you....

:)

Comment: here set height dynamically for each textview and also set scrollview content size.. :)